# continuos smooth incremental rotation of a node (camera)

Tags: ios, rotation, quaternions, scenekit

I'm trying to incrementally rotate the camera around x-axis by 5 degrees. it works fine except for  animation at 355 jumps suddenly. it happens due to animation chaining. if my following method is called in `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` then it is not time based rotation. the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` is triggered in each frame. and it means my scene animation action with duration is not ready yet. by lowering the animation duration, the animation is not smooth anymore. doing a timer based with same interval as the animation duration looks bad as well. is there anyway to get this animation smooth?

```
-(void) updateCameraRotation
{
     SCNQuaternion oldRotScnQuat = _cameraNode.presentationNode.rotation;
     GLKQuaternion glQuatOldRot = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(oldRotScnQuat.w, oldRotScnQuat.x, oldRotScnQuat.y, oldRotScnQuat.z);

     float xan = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(5);
     GLKQuaternion newx = GLKQuaternionIdentity;
     GLKVector3 vec = GLKVector3Normalize(GLKVector3Make(1, 0, 0));
     double result = sinf(xan/2);
     newx = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(cosf(xan/2), vec.x *result, vec.y * result, vec.z * result);
     newx = GLKQuaternionNormalize(newx);
     glQuatOldRot = GLKQuaternionMultiply(glQuatOldRot, newx);

     axis = GLKQuaternionAxis(glQuatOldRot);
     angle = GLKQuaternionAngle(glQuatOldRot);


    [_cameraNode runAction:[SCNAction rotateToAxisAngle:SCNVector4Make(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z, angle) duration:1]];
}
```

Comment: it's true that the delegate methods are called at every frame. But what do you mean by "it means my scene animation action with duration is not ready yet" ?

Comment: if the animation duration is for instance 5 sec long then in this 5 sec delegate is triggered 60 timer per second. so the method is called 300 times during the animation. and it would 300 x 5 degrees rotation. so thats no good. i tried to cancel previous animation as well even removed the action but it didn't help.

Comment: i think I'm doing something wrong with the angle. is that the correct way to keep it rotating?

Comment: if your code is running at 60fps maybe you don't need animation. Or you can use implicit animations instead of actions. With implicit animations (see `SCNTransaction`) an animation will be automatically created from the current value to new value, and there is no need to cancel previous calls.

Comment: 60 fps was just an example and it will not be the case on ipad 2 for example. The rotation is not forever. it's controlled by device orientation and/or virtual joystick. if the user keeps pressing the button in a direction it will rotate the camera, otherwise it will be stationary.

Comment: implicit animations do not repeat, you will be able to achieve what you want with them.

Comment: it is the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLERP is used to make smooth rotations between two known attitudes. Try and avoid needless conversions between axis-angle and quaternions (leave them in quaternions if possible).
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/slerp/

You will also need to calculate the angle between the quaternion axes: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/quaternion-distance

I have used both these functions myself and they work well.
Rather than adding 5 degrees per frame, you can specify a scalar t in the range of [0, 1].

For instance, when rotating from quaternion P to Q, R = SLERP(P,Q,t) will give you the quaternion R from P to Q. If t = 0 then R = P, if t = 1 then R = Q.

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide a CABasicAnimation with byValue set to your 5 degrees and set repititions to be infinite. Won't that work?